# QT5 webkit plugin issue

Tags: qt, plugins, qt4, qt5

I have application created using QT 5.0.2. When launch the video window, blank screen is observed. I am using win8 64-bit OS(also VLC). There is no issue with QT4 in win7 32-bit. Video streaming is perfect. Using qt webit/webpage classes

---

Is there any way to check: whether plug-in(mainly to view the video frames) is enabled or not in qt web-kit browser ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qt 4.8 and latest version 5.0.2 doesn't support video.. here is the link
 [http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/23636][1]

You can resolve the issue by using this blog. Sorry I did not tried this. may help you. You need to build qt twice and few more corrections!
[http://blog.enthought.com/open-source/fun-with-qtwebkit-html5-video/][2]

Some one already mentioned the qt open bug against it.
[https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-22883][3]